# iframe Sec-Fetch-Dest on FIREFOX

Tags: symfony, firefox, iframe

I am trying to use an iframe to connect to my website form another domain. I use Sec-Fetch-Dest to know if the website is being called from the iframe or not.

This works good on Google Chrome but seems to not work on Firefox !
How can I make this work form firefox too ? is there any other way to find out if the website is being called from the iframe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MDN, this is not supported on Firefox or Safari (or IE, but no surprises there!) at present:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Dest

More peculiarly, the page there does not even mention 'iframe' as a possible value, though both Chrome and Edge are supplying that as you have observed. The specification for these Sec-Fetch headers is still a working draft though (with an editor from Google), so I guess Chrome is forging ahead, and Edge is just along for the Chromium ride. For reference, here's the current draft spec:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Dest

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any reliable way to detect requests inside an iframe coming from Firefox. If you control the initial `src` URL for the iframe, you could include a query parameter, but this will naturally not carry forward with any navigations inside the frame thereafter.